# Increment a variable with some letters in it

Tags: php, mysql, string

I want to store records in my database with these values as their reference_id

```
CD000001
CD000002
CD000003
CD000004
etc
```

before I save a record, I want check the last record's reference_id then add one for the next record. For example, the next record should be **CD000005**

I can fetch the last record, the do a `substr($var, 2);` to get rid of the **CD** part so that I can do calculations. However what I get is CD5. I don't want to manually inject those `00000` because when I reach record 10, there will be a crisis. I will get `CD0000010` instead of `CD000010.`

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried seeing what happens if you do `$myVar = 'CD000001; $myVar++; echo $myVar;`?

Comment: But relying on PHP incrementing a value to avoid duplication in database records isn't good or effective

Comment: I agree with @MarkBaker.  You want to rely on MySQL's auto increment capabilities here instead of using PHP.

Comment: why u can't keep another increment filed to calc max

Comment: my suggestion would be take off CD and store it in a $variable and let the numbers do their thing, but when you call it for displaying purposes you can simple concatenate it with reference_id

Comment: I suggest you have your primary key as regular autoincrement integer; then either have a separate field for your business ID if you are entering it manually, or just format it for output in the above manner if you know your business ID will always be "CD" + padded DB id. Also, don't "inject" `00000`, use proper formatting: `sprintf("CD%06d", 10);` gives proper `"CD000010"`, no crisis.

Comment: Why a crisis? You can keep incrementing and padding the result on the left

Comment: Especially if you are writing a web application (and since you're using PHP, chances are good that you are), you really really don't want to increment your IDs by yourself, since you can get into a race condition, which will give two of your objects the same ID; autoincrement field in the database is exactly the right countermeasure for it, and you shouldn't be inventing your own homebrew solution.

Comment: @MarkBaker Your answer is what I wanted. Thanks y'all.

Comment: No, it really isn't. @MarkBaker gave you the literal PHP solution, and warned you that you shouldn't be using it in the very next comment. It's just like going to a construction yard, having the supervisor tell you "paper hats are not effective protection against stones falling on your head", and you latching onto "so, paper hats, huh? okay, i need one of those!"

Comment: lol. Okay, I'll go with @mike. O. answer

Answer (score 3):

Use PHP's str_pad function. As an example:

```
$next_record = 'CD'. str_pad($last_auto_increment_id, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following

```
mysql> create table test (val varchar(100));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)
mysql> insert into test values ('CD000001'),('CD000002'),('CD000003'),('CD000004');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test ;
+----------+
| val      |
+----------+
| CD000001 |
| CD000002 |
| CD000003 |
| CD000004 |
+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now to get the last record you may use the following technique

```
select * from test 
order by cast( substring_index(val,'CD',-1) as unsigned) desc limit 1 ;

+----------+
| val      |
+----------+
| CD000004 |
+----------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now while selecting you can get the value - 'CD' as

```
mysql> select substring_index(val,'CD',-1) as val 
from test order by cast( substring_index(val,'CD',-1) as unsigned) desc limit 1 ;
+--------+
| val    |
+--------+
| 000004 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Mysql `LPAD()` function:

```
SELECT LPAD( '8' , 6, '0');
  --> returns "000008"
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, if you got CD000004 in one of the variable. say $var

So,
$var = 'CD000004';
$with_cd_var = substr($var, 2) + 1;

$final_val = 'CD'.str_pad($with_cd_var, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

The $final_val contain the the string as "CD000005"

Answer (score 0):

Get reference_id by using str_pad PHP function:

$reference_id = 'CD'. str_pad(($reference_id+1), 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);